# Apache Kafka appends wrong JAVA path

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I have installed the OpenJDK Headless JAVA package on a Ubuntu 16.04 which works fine. My `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

But when I'm starting Apache Kafka it tries to load JAVA from the wrong path. It looks like it is appending `/bin/java` to the end of the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

```
$ sudo /opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/config/server.properties 

/opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 271: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/opt/kafka/kafka_2.11-1.1.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 271: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

I tried changing `JAVA_HOME` to just:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
```

But it is still pointing to the same (invalid) java executable.

I then inspected the 271 line in kafka-run-class.sh which says:

```
exec $JAVA $KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS $KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS $KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS $KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $KAFKA_OPTS "$@"
```

So it looks like it is using the `JAVA` variable, so I try to export 
 `JAVA="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"` without any luck.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and how I can solve this?

Comment: Seems Kafka needs JDK and not JRE. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_installation_steps.htm

Comment: I had the same problem an resolved it by [setting JAVA_HOME variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users).

Answer (score 3):

1. `sudo vi ~/.bashrc`
2. Edit your java home to below

```bsh
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

3. `source  ~/.bashrc`
4. then start Kafka

```bsh
    ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties
```